# timber/twig how to pass `posts` php-object to JavaScript? Some values are lost

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

When I'm trying to pass the information contained in `{{posts}}` I cannot retrieve all of it, at least not the `post.link` information

```js
  {% for post in posts %}
    <script>
      var t = JSON.parse('{{post|json_encode(constant('JSON_HEX_APOS'))|e('js')}}')
      t.link = '{{post.link}}'
      console.log(t)
    </script>
  {% endfor %}
```

Without manually adding the `link`, it doesn't show up

Why is this happening and how could I workaround this?

EDIT: related https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/1434

Comment: `json_encode` will only encode public attributes, try making `link` more visible or implement `JsonSerializable` and override [jsonSerialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn’t encode your whole post object. You should encode all the values you need separately.

The `link` for your post doesn’t show up, because `link` is not a property, but [a method of the `Timber\Post` object](https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/d160d7a88144969dd196abeb513816a905eea690/lib/Post.php#L1352-L1358). This might be a little bit confusing, because in Twig we use `{{ post.link }}`. It looks like it’s a property or maybe an array item. But we could also use `{{ post.link() }}`, which is the same as `{{ post.link }}`. You can read more about this in the [Variables section](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#variables) in *Twig for Template Designers*.

So what I would do is **build a new array with the data you need** and encode it to JSON in PHP with `wp_json_encode()`.

**PHP**

```php
$posts_json = [];

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    $posts_json[] = wp_json_encode( [
        'title' => $post->title(),
        'link' => $post->link(),
    ] );
}

$context['posts_json'] = $posts_json;
```

By only adding the data you need, you keep the output in the frontend small. Otherwise, you would end up with a lot of data that you will never and that only increases the page size unnecessarily.

And then in **Twig**, you could do it like this:

```
{% for post in posts_json %}
    <script>
      var t = {{ post }}
      console.log(t)
    </script>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thousand thanks! Is there a benefit in doing the structure in `php` and passing it to the context, versus doing everything directly in `twig` (since the information is already in the context)?

Comment: You might find developers who have hard opinions on this. I usually try to not have too much logic in Twig and mostly use it to display data, but it’s totally fine to do it in Twig.